# On the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(n^a\right)}{n^b}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> Given the infinite series
>
> $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\end{aligned} \frac{\sin\left(n^a\right)}{n^b}$$
>
> with $a,\,b \in \mathbb{R}$, study when it converges and when it diverges.

---

**Easy cases**

- $\forall\,a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\left|\frac{\sin\left(n^a\right)}{n^b}\right| \le \frac{1}{n^b}$ so the series $\color{green}{\text{converges}}$ for $b > 1$.
- If $a \le 0$ we have $\frac{\sin\left(n^a\right)}{n^b} \le \frac{1}{n^{b-a}}$ so the series $\color{blue}{\text{diverges}}$ for $b \le a + 1$ and $\color{green}{\text{converges}}$ for $b > a + 1$.
- If $a > 0 \, \land \, b \le 0$ we have $\not\exists \begin{aligned}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(n^a\right)}{n^b} \end{aligned}$ so the series  $\color{blue}{\text{diverges}}$.
- If $a = 1\, \land \, b > 0$ the series $\color{green}{\text{converges}}$ by *Abel-Dirichlet's test*.

**Hard cases**

- If $0 < a < 1\, \land \, 0 < b \le 1-a$ the series $\color{blue}{\text{diverges}}$ by [proof of i707107](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3283071/247735).

  - If $0 < a < \frac{1}{2}\, \land \, a < b \le 1-a$ the series $\color{blue}{\text{diverges}}$ by [proof of RRL](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2375271/247735).
- If $0 < a < 1\, \land \, b > 1-a$ the series $\color{green}{\text{converges}}$ by [proof of i707107](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3283071/247735).

  - If $a > 0\, \land \, b > \max(a,\,1-a)$ the series $\color{green}{\text{converges}}$ by [proof of RRL](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2375271/247735).
- If $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}, $ $k-1 < a < k\, \land \, b > 1 - \frac{k-a}{2^k-2}$ the series $\color{green}{\text{converges}}$ by [proof of i707107](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3283071/247735).
- If $a > 0 \, \land \, b = 1$ the series $\color{green}{\text{converges}}$ by [proof David Speyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2275/247735) (+ *i707107* in the comments).
- If $a = 2 \, \land \, 0 < b \le \frac{1}{2}$ the series $\color{blue}{\text{diverges}}$ ([Theorem 2.30](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485887376) by *Hardy&Littlewood*).

[image]

---

$\color{red}{\textbf{Open cases}}$

- $a = \frac{3}{2} \land b = \frac{1}{4}$:
  [image]
- $a = \frac{3}{2} \land b = \frac{1}{2}$:
  [image]
- $a = \frac{3}{2} \land b = \frac{3}{4}$:
  [image]
- $a = 2 \land b = \frac{3}{4}$:
  [image]
- $a = \frac{5}{2} \land b = \frac{1}{2}$:
  [image]

Comment: Actually, consider $a+1<b\le0$.  That is, the series will converge for $a<b-1$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: For $a<0$, you can use the limit comparison with the sequence $\frac{1}{n^{b-a}}$ to conclude your sequence is convergent for $(b-a)>1$ and divergent for $(b-a)\leq 1$.

Comment: For $b = 1$ and all $a > 0$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2270/148510).  That was not easy and  the region where $0 < b < 1$ and $a > 1$ probably no easier to analyze.

Comment: Please, try to concentrate all new information in one single edit. Don't make a lot of edits.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo The nature of this problem is that many people's collective effort improve the result. So, a lot of edits is inevitable.

Comment: @TeM One thing to remark is that the solution by David Speyer is for all "integers" $a>0$ and $b=1$. In such case we indeed have convergence for $b>1-\epsilon(a)$ for some function $\epsilon(a)$ satisfying $\epsilon(a)\rightarrow 0$ as $a\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @TeM although David Speyer’s solution is for integer $a>0$, $b=1$, the series is convergent for indeed ”ALL” $a>0$, $b=1$. The method of mine uses Van Der Corput’s method. The application or Van Der Corput for integer $a$ is Weyl’s inequality in David Speyer’s answer. The method can be applied to real $a>0$ too. More about the method are outlined in chapter 4 and 5 of Titchmarsh’s book.

Comment: @TeM I explained more about the previous comment in my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The series diverges if $0<a<1$, $b>0$ and $a+b\leq 1$**

This idea is already discussed in the link provided at $a=b=1/2$ case. 
Let $k$ be a positive integer. If 
$$
2\pi k + \pi/6\leq n^a\leq 2\pi k + 5\pi/6,
$$
then $\sin (n^a)\geq 1/2$.

The number of $n$'s in this interval is $\asymp k^{(1/a) -1}$. In the interval, we have $n^b\asymp k^{b/a}$. Thus, the contribution of $n$'s to the sum in this interval is $\asymp k^{(1/a)-(b/a)-1}$.

If $(1/a)-(b/a)-1 \geq 0$, then we have divergence. Note that the partial sum of the series fails to be Cauchy sequence.

**The series converges if $0<a<1$ and $a+b>1$**

The case particularly requires a good estimation of the sum by an integral. A crucial lemma for this case is Lemma 4.8 of The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function written by Titchmarsh.

> Let $f(x)$ be a real differentiable function in the interval $[a,b]$, let $f'(x)$ be monotonic, and let $|f'(x)|\leq \theta <1$. Then
>   $$
> \sum_{a<n\leq b}e^{2\pi i f(n)} =  \int_a^b e^{2\pi i f(x)} \ dx + O(1).
> $$

Let $0<a<1$. We apply the above with $f(x)=\frac{x^a}{2\pi}$. The assumptions of the lemma are satisfied for $x\geq X_0>0$. Then we obtain

$$
\sum_{X_0<n\leq N} e^{in^a}=\int_{X_0}^N e^{ix^a} \ dx + O(1).
$$

Apply change of variable $x^a=t$, then 
$$
\int_{X_0}^N e^{ix^a} \ dx = \int_{X_0^a}^{N^a} e^{it} \frac1a t^{\frac1a -1} \ dt.
$$

Now, integration by parts shows that the above integral is $O(N^{1-a})$. Thus, we have for $t\geq 1$, 
$$
\sum_{n\leq t} \sin(n^a) = O(t^{1-a}).
$$

Then the partial summation yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(n^a)}{n^b} = O(N^{1-a-b})+b\int_{1-}^N \frac{\sum_{n\leq t} \sin(n^a)}{t^{b+1}} \ dt.
$$

Hence, we have the convergence when $b>1-a$.

**The series converges if $k\in\mathbb{Z}\cap [2,\infty)$, $k-1<a<k$, and $b>1-\frac k{2^k-2}+\frac a{2^k-2}$**

We apply Theorems 5.11-5.13 of The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function written by Titchmarsh. These theorems are proved by Van Der Corput's method. If the  method is applied to integer $a$, we obtain [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality), which was used in [David Speyer's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-sinnk-n/2275#2275). The method is outlined in Chapter 5 of Titchmarsh's book.

> Let $f(x)$ be real and have continuous derivatives up to $k$-th order, where $k\geq 2$. Let $\lambda_k\leq f^{(k)}(x)\leq h\lambda_k$ (or the same for $-f^{(k)}(x)$). Let $b-a\geq 1$, $K=2^{k-1}$. Then 
>   $$
> \sum_{a<n\leq b} e^{2\pi i f(n)}=O(h^{\frac2K}(b-a)\lambda_k^{\frac1{2K-2}})+O((b-a)^{1-\frac2K}\lambda_k^{-\frac1{2K-2}}).$$

For the series in question, use $f(n)=\frac{n^a}{2\pi}$ over diadic intervals $(N,2N]$, and $\lambda_k\asymp N^{a-k}$. Then for $N\geq 1$, 
$$
\sum_{N<n\leq 2N} \sin(n^a)=O(N^{1-\frac{k-a}{2^k-2}}).
$$
Here, the implied constant depends only on $a$. Then adding up the results for diadic intervals, we obtain for $t\geq 1$, 
$$
\sum_{n\leq t} \sin(n^a)=O(t^{1-\frac{k-a}{2^k-2}}).
$$
Applying partial summation, we obtain 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(n^a)}{n^b} = O(N^{1-\frac{k-a}{2^k-2}-b})+b\int_{1-}^N \frac{\sum_{n\le t} \sin(n^a)}{t^{b+1}}\ dt.
$$
Then the convergence of the series follows if $b>1-\frac k{2^k-2}+\frac a{2^k-2}$.

Answer (score 16):

If $a > 0$ then the series converges if $b > \max(a,1-a)$.

The general principle is that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ and the integral $\int_1^\infty f(x) \, dx$ converge and diverge together if $\int_1^\infty |f'(x)| \, dx < \infty$. This is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2068845/148510).

In this case, $f(x) = \sin x^a /x^b$ and

$$\int_1^\infty |f'(x)| \, dx= \int_1^\infty \left| \frac{-b\sin x^a}{x^{b+1}} + \frac{a\cos x^a}{x^{b-a+1}} \right| \, dx \\ \leqslant \int_1^\infty  \frac{b}{x^{b+1}} \, dx + \int_1^\infty  \frac{a}{x^{b-a+1}} \, dx, $$

so the integrals on the RHS converge  and theorem is applicable if $b > 0$ and $b > a$.

We have

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x^a}{x^b}\, dx = \frac{1}{a}\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u^{(b+a-1)/a}}\, du, $$

which converges by the Dirichlet test when $a > 0$ and $b+a-1 > 0 \implies b > 1 - a.$

If $b \leqslant 1 - a$ then the integral diverges.  In this case we have an integral of the form $\int_1^\infty u^\alpha \sin u \, du$ where $\alpha \geqslant 0$.  Divergence is obvious if $\alpha = 0$ since $\int_1^c \sin u \, du  = \cos 1 - \cos c$.

For $\alpha > 0$ we have for any positive integer $k$,

$$\left|\int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi} u^\alpha  \sin u \, du \right| = \int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi} u^\alpha  \sin u \, du \geqslant (2 k \pi)^\alpha\int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi} \sin u \, du = 2(2k\pi)^\alpha.$$

Since the RHS tends to $\infty$ as $k \to \infty$, the Cauchy criterion is violated and the improper integral must diverge.

Hence, the series diverges when $0 < a < b \leqslant 1 - a$.

Comment: You're welcome. This should fill some of the remaining area.

Comment: Also when $0 < a < b$ and the integral test applies, the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x^a}{x^b} \, dx$ diverges when $ b \leqslant 1-a$ and, hence, the series diverges as well.

Comment: Here we have an integral of the form $\int_1^\infty u^\alpha \sin u \, du$ with $\alpha \geqslant 0$.  This obviously diverges, but I added a proof to the answer.