# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \sqrt{n}}{n^p}$ converge while $0<p\le \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The original range for $p$ is $p>0.$ It obviously converges when $p>1$. If $\frac{1}{2}<p \le 1$, it's not hard to prove the convergence by comparing it with its integral. But it became much harder when $0<p\le \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374620

Comment: But also https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask