# Similar to the Integral Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2068845), it is said that

> If $\int_{1}^{\infty}\vert f'(x)\rvert \,\mathrm{d}x$ converges, then
>   $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ converge or diverge together.

In the proof, it says that

> $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left | f(k)-\int_{k-1}^{k}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right |<\infty$$
>   implies the convergence of
>   $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} f(k)-\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Why does this implication hold? If think some conditions of $f$ is missing here.

Also, this idea brings me another question: Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two sequences of numbers. Is it true in general that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n+b_n|$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converge? It is clear if those sequences were positive, but what if at least of them were negative?

Comment: There is no condition of $f$ missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was shown that we have (absolute) convergence of

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left|f(k) - \int_{k-1}^k f(x) \, dx \right|$$

By the comparison test, this implies convergence  of

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left[f(k) - \int_{k-1}^k f(x) \, dx \right],$$

and there exists a finite limit $L$ such that

$$L = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left[f(k) - \int_{k-1}^k f(x) \, dx \right] = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[ \sum_{k=2}^n f(k) - \sum_{k=2}^n \int_{k-1}^k f(x) \, dx\right] \\ =  \lim_{n \to \infty}  \left[ \underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)}_{A_n} - \underbrace{\int_{1}^n f(x) \, dx}_{B_n} \right]$$

If either one of $A_n$ or $B_n$ converge, then the other must converge.  For example, if $A_n \to A$ as $n \to \infty$, then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} B_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}[A_n - (A_n - B_n)] = \lim_{n\to \infty}A_n - \lim_{n\to \infty}(A_n - B_n) = A- L$$

If either one of $A_n$ and $B_n$ does not converge (diverges to $\pm \infty$ or the limit fails to exist), then the other must not converge.

For example, if the limit of $A_n$ fails to exist we have

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \,A_n \neq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \,A_n,$$

and

$$\begin{align} \limsup_{n \to \infty} \,B_n &= \limsup_{n \to \infty} \,\, [A_n - (A_n - B_n)] \\ &= \limsup_{n \to \infty} \, A_n - \limsup_{n \to \infty}\,\, (A_n - B_n) \\&=  \limsup_{n \to \infty} \, A_n - L \\ &\neq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \,\, A_n - L\\ &= \liminf_{n \to \infty} \, A_n - \liminf_{n \to \infty} \,\,(A_n - B_n) \\ &=  \liminf_{n \to \infty} \,\, [A_n - (A_n - B_n)] \\ &= \liminf_{n \to \infty} \, B_n \end{align} $$

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a question. Does "X and Y converge or diverge together" not mean that "X converges if and only if Y converges"? If yes, is it not enough to put as follows: Define $L_n:=A_n-B_n$. It is shown that $(L_n)$ converges to $L$. If $(A_n)$ converges, then $(L_n+B_n)$ converges, and so $(B_n)$ converges, because $B_n=(L_n+B_n)-L_n$. The other direction is similar, i.e. if $(B_n)$ converges, then $(A_n)$ converges. Then we are done. Here, I didn't mention about the divergence, like you mentioned in the last paragraph. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: That's fine -- you are just restating my first argument $B_n = (L_n + B_n) - L_n  \iff B_n =  A_n - (A_n - B_n)$ where $L_n = A_n - B_n$.

Comment: That's a relief. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @UnknownW: You're welcome. Happy to help.

Comment: By the way, did you figure this test out yourself or is there a reference that explains about this test? I am just curious if I could find something more like this.

Comment: @UnknownW:  I figured this out some time ago when I was trying to determine convergence of series like $\sum \frac{\sin n^a}{n^b}$ where the Dirichlet test fails.  By estimating the difference $f(k) - \int_{k-1}^k f(x) \, dx$ I could sometimes find a comparison that helped. I have never seen this in basic calculus or analysis textbooks which only discuss the elementary integral test for nonnegative, monotone functions.  Later I did some research and found old papers that talked about extensions of the integral test including one by the famous mathematician GH Hardy who worked with Ramanujan.

Comment: It is not obvious that the convergence of $\int_0^{+\infty} f$ is equivalent to the convergence of the sequence $\int_0^n f$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, by the additivity of the integral and the triangle inequality,
\begin{align} \left| \sum_{k=2}^\infty f(k)- \int_0^1 f(x) \mathrm dx \right| &= \left| \sum_{k=2}^\infty f(k)- \sum_{k=2}^\infty \int_{k-1}^k f(x) \mathrm dx \right|\\
&= \left|\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(f(k)- \int_{k-1}^k f(x) \mathrm dx\right)\right|\\
&\leq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left|f(k)- \int_{k-1}^k f(x) \mathrm dx\right| < \infty.
\end{align}
For your second question, take $a_n = n = -b_n$. Then $ a_n + b_n = 0$, so
$ \sum |a_n+b_n| = 0, $ but $\sum a_n = -\sum b_n = \sum n$ which is divergent.

Comment: Can you explain how/why it implies the conclusion, and is from the first to the second line justified? Thanks for the counter example ...